# Why I cannot work on my terminal when my VPN application is connected?

Tags: pantheon-terminal, vpn

I am new with the os and I really like it. But I got a problem when working in the terminal when my VPN is active. For instance when I run the command sudo apt-get update on the terminal while my VPN is active it always produces connection failed status. But when I turn off my VPN the command runs and fineshes smoothly. Though it is not a big problem, it is just troublesome to switch off my VPN application every time I use my terminal.

Comment: This sounds to me like the VPN is blocking traffic to the repositories, either to limit bandwidth consumption or some other reason. Which provider are you using?

Comment: Im just using nordvpn